# Replicating result of gdalwarp using gdal Python bindings

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, numpy

I am trying to re-project/resample with the GDAL python bindings, but am getting slightly different results compared to those from the command line utility `gdalwarp`.

**See update below for shorter example**

This script illustrates the Python approach:

```
from osgeo import osr, gdal
import numpy


def reproject_point(point, srs, target_srs):
    '''
    Reproject a pair of coordinates from one spatial reference system to
    another.
    '''
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(srs, target_srs)
    (x, y, z) = transform.TransformPoint(*point)

    return (x, y)


def reproject_bbox(top_left, bottom_right, srs, dest_srs):
    x_min, y_max = top_left
    x_max, y_min = bottom_right
    corners = [
        (x_min, y_max),
        (x_max, y_max),
        (x_max, y_min),
        (x_min, y_min)]
    projected_corners = [reproject_point(crnr, srs, dest_srs)
                         for crnr in corners]

    dest_top_left = (min([crnr[0] for crnr in projected_corners]),
                     max([crnr[1] for crnr in projected_corners]))
    dest_bottom_right = (max([crnr[0] for crnr in projected_corners]),
                         min([crnr[1] for crnr in projected_corners]))

    return dest_top_left, dest_bottom_right


################################################################################
# Create synthetic data
gtiff_drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
w, h = 512, 512
raster = numpy.zeros((w, h), dtype=numpy.uint8)
raster[::w / 10, :] = 255
raster[:, ::h / 10] = 255
top_left = (-109764, 215677)
pixel_size = 45

src_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
src_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3413)

src_geotran = [top_left[0], pixel_size, 0,
               top_left[1], 0, -pixel_size]

rows, cols = raster.shape
src_ds = gtiff_drv.Create(
    'test_epsg3413.tif',
    cols, rows, 1,
    gdal.GDT_Byte)
src_ds.SetGeoTransform(src_geotran)
src_ds.SetProjection(src_srs.ExportToWkt())
src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)


################################################################################
# Reproject to EPSG: 3573 and upsample to 7m
dest_pixel_size = 7

dest_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
dest_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3573)

# Calculate new bounds by re-projecting old corners
x_min, y_max = top_left
bottom_right = (x_min + cols * pixel_size,
                y_max - rows * pixel_size)
dest_top_left, dest_bottom_right = reproject_bbox(
    top_left, bottom_right,
    src_srs, dest_srs)

# Make dest dataset
x_min, y_max = dest_top_left
x_max, y_min = dest_bottom_right
new_rows = int((x_max - x_min) / float(dest_pixel_size))
new_cols = int((y_max - y_min) / float(dest_pixel_size))
dest_ds = gtiff_drv.Create(
    'test_epsg3573.tif',
    new_rows, new_cols, 1,
    gdal.GDT_Byte)
dest_geotran = (dest_top_left[0], dest_pixel_size, 0,
                dest_top_left[1], 0, -dest_pixel_size)
dest_ds.SetGeoTransform(dest_geotran)
dest_ds.SetProjection(dest_srs.ExportToWkt())

# Perform the projection/resampling
gdal.ReprojectImage(
    src_ds, dest_ds,
    src_srs.ExportToWkt(), dest_srs.ExportToWkt(),
    gdal.GRA_NearestNeighbour)

dest_data = dest_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

# Close datasets
src_ds = None
dest_ds = None
```

Compare with output of:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3413 -t_srs EPSG:3573 -tr 7 7 -r near -of GTiff test_epsg3413.tif test_epsg3573_gdalwarp.tif
```

They differ in size (by 2 rows and 1 column) as well as with some differing pixel values near edges.

See transparent overlay of test_epsg3573.tif and test_epsg3573_gdalwarp.tif below. If images were identical there would only be black and white pixels, no grey.

[image: QGIS overlay of test_epsg3573.tif and test_epsg3573_gdalwarp.tif]

Tested with Python 2.7.8, GDAL 1.11.1, Numpy 1.9.1

**Update**:

Here is a much shorter example. This seems to not be caused by upsampling as the following also produces results inconsistent with `gdalwarp`

```
from osgeo import osr, gdal
import numpy


# Create synthetic data
gtiff_drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
w, h = 512, 512
raster = numpy.zeros((w, h), dtype=numpy.uint8)
raster[::w / 10, :] = 255
raster[:, ::h / 10] = 255
top_left = (-109764, 215677)
pixel_size = 45

src_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
src_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3413)

src_geotran = [top_left[0], pixel_size, 0,
               top_left[1], 0, -pixel_size]

rows, cols = raster.shape
src_ds = gtiff_drv.Create(
    'test_epsg3413.tif',
    cols, rows, 1,
    gdal.GDT_Byte)
src_ds.SetGeoTransform(src_geotran)
src_ds.SetProjection(src_srs.ExportToWkt())
src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)

# Reproject to EPSG: 3573
dest_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
dest_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3573)

int_ds = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(src_ds, src_srs.ExportToWkt(), dest_srs.ExportToWkt())

# Make dest dataset
dest_ds = gtiff_drv.Create(
    'test_epsg3573_avrt.tif',
    int_ds.RasterXSize, int_ds.RasterYSize, 1,
    gdal.GDT_Byte)
dest_ds.SetGeoTransform(int_ds.GetGeoTransform())
dest_ds.SetProjection(int_ds.GetProjection())
dest_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(int_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

# Close datasets
src_ds = None
dest_ds = None
```

And this is the gdalwarp call that I expect to be the same, yet is not:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3413 -t_srs EPSG:3573 -of GTiff test_epsg3413.tif test_epsg3573_gdalwarp.tif
```

The image below shows each resulting binary image overlayed at 50% transparency. The light grey pixels are inconsistencies between the two results.

[image: Inconsistency illustrated in QGIS]

Comment: Have you tried `gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(source_file, source_srs_wkt, dest_srs_wkt)`?

Comment: Thanks Luke, did not know this function. Tried just now, but some pixels are still different between the two.  I.e., the geo-transforms and shapes of the rasters are identical (when not up-sampled), but some pixels seem to be resampled differently. This at least demonstrates the issue is still present even when not up-sampling.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I get the same results as `gdalwarp` from `gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT` if I set the error threshold to 0.125 to match the default (-et) in [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html). Alternatively, you could set `-et 0.0` in your call to `gdalwarp` to match the default in `gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT`.

**Example**

Create a reference to compare to:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 byte.tif warp_ref.tif
```

Run the projection in Python (based on code from the "warp_27() function in the GDAL [autotest suite](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/alg/warp.py)):

```
# Open source dataset
src_ds = gdal.Open('byte.tif')

# Define target SRS
dst_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
dst_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
dst_wkt = dst_srs.ExportToWkt()

error_threshold = 0.125  # error threshold --> use same value as in gdalwarp
resampling = gdal.GRA_NearestNeighbour

# Call AutoCreateWarpedVRT() to fetch default values for target raster dimensions and geotransform
tmp_ds = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT( src_ds,
                                   None, # src_wkt : left to default value --> will use the one from source
                                   dst_wkt,
                                   resampling,
                                   error_threshold )

# Create the final warped raster
dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').CreateCopy('warp_test.tif', tmp_ds)
dst_ds = None

# Check that we have the same result as produced by 'gdalwarp -rb -t_srs EPSG:4326 ....'

ref_ds = gdal.Open('warp_ref.tif')
ref_cs = ref_ds.GetRasterBand(1).Checksum()

ds = gdal.Open('warp_test.tif')
cs = ds1.GetRasterBand(1).Checksum()

if cs == ref_cs:
    print 'success, they match'
else:
    print "fail, they don't match"
```