# Raster interpolation with gdalwarp, and replicating with python API

Tags: python, gdal, interpolation, gdalwarp

My problem is similar to this: [Replicating result of gdalwarp using gdal Python bindings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139906/replicating-result-of-gdalwarp-using-gdal-python-bindings). I want to resample a raster using bilinear interpolation, which I've done successfully with gdalwarp by adding height and width specifications for the output file:

```
gdalwarp -ts w_output h_output -r bilinear -co 'TFW=YES' -of VRT input.tif output.vrt
```

I'm trying to replicate the above result using the Python API. Can it be done using gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT?

```
src_ds = gdal.Open(input.tif)
src_wkt = None
dst_wkt = ????
resampling = gdal.GRA_Bilinear
output_vrt = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(src_ds, src_wkt, dst_wkt, resampling)
```

I'm guessing I have to do something clever with the dst_wkt in order to replicate the above gdalwarp result. I just want to increase the number of pixels by a factor of 10 compared to the input raster.

P.S. If it's better to just use gdalwarp, that's good to know. I have no problem doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have now a better way to do.

Since [RFC 59.1 : GDAL/OGR utilities as a library](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library), you can use `gdalwarp` from Python directly without using any call to the command line utility but using really the function from Python.

This solution is a bit "on the edge" as you need at the moment to use the latest GDAL version (version 2.1, in fact the master/trunk version)