# How to replicate gdalwarp -cutline in Python to cut out tif image based on the extents.kml file

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, extents, gdalwarp

In my python code I run the following command:

```
command = 'gdalwarp rgb.tif rgb_output_cut.tif -cutline extent.kml -dstnodata 0 -q'
os.system(command)
```

This cuts `rgb.tif` based on the extents specified in `extent.kml` and outputs a file called `rgb_output_cut.tif`. I would like to run this command without `gdalwarp` but instead with Python bindings. Is anyone familiar with this? Also, for the purposes of my task, having `-dstnodata 0` is optional, it is just nice to have.

I found similar [examples](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139906/replicating-result-of-gdalwarp-using-gdal-python-bindings), however, they are just using `gdalwarp` for reprojection. For my case I'd like to cut out an extent.

Here, in my `extent.kml` file it is just a series of LinearRing Polygons, for example:

```
  <Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
  <Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-104.959386510378,39.7075208980859 -104.959394642483,39.7020277743643 -104.968738431214,39.7020465443243 -104.968779091739,39.7075083857725 -104.959386510378,39.7075208980859</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

Not, I must use gdal version `1.10.1`.

Comment: Extent, as in envelope? Consider GDAL_Translate -projwin Xmin Ymax Xmax Ymin (I think the parameters are in that order).. doesn't warp unless you tell it to adjust the pixel size so is much faster, you would just need a way to get the extent out of the KML. Instead of os.system have a look at subprocess.Popen, I find it works better.

Comment: My `extent.kml` file is just a series of LinearRing Polygons, I updated my post with an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975952/get-feature-extent-using-gdal-ogr use the KML or LIBKML driver, whichever works on your install. inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("KML") then the rest of it should work as normal.. that is if the layer from the kml doesn't support GetExtent http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#GetExtent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the GDAL Python bindings (GDAL >= 2.1), it should be:

```
from osgeo import gdal

input_raster = "path/to/rgb.tif"
output_raster = "path/to/rgb_output_cut.tif"
input_kml = "path/to/extent.kml"

ds = gdal.Warp(output_raster,
              input_raster,
              format = 'GTiff',
              cutlineDSName = input_kml,
              cutlineLayer = 'extent',
              dstNodata = 0)
ds = None
```