# gdal.Warp -cutline option (geometry object instead of vector file)

Tags: polygon, gdalwarp

I am new to ogr and vector data manipulation.

I am interested to cut an image (in this case a DEM file) using gdal.Warp() with the '-cutline' option to used the borders of a rectangular polygon to cut the underlying image. I saw good examples [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262021/how-to-replicate-gdalwarp-cutline-in-python-to-cut-out-tif-image-based-on-the-e/343913?noredirect=1#comment561734_343913)

I wonder if it is possible to provide a "polygon object" instead of a "vector file"(.kml, .shp etc.) as the input to "cutlineDSName"?

Comment: A polygon object as for example the [Shapely.Polygon](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#Polygon) will not work, but an opened vector dataset (`ds = ogr.Open(vectorfn)`) should work.

Answer (score 1):

I did that a few days ago. I am not an expert in Python so perhaps there are other ways to achieve that. Don't forget to import all the modules you need.

- First, you can convert your DEM into an array of value 1 representing the extent of your DEM:

> ```
> # input (dem)
> dem = dem.tif
>
> # output (dem extent)
> extent = extent.tif
>
> # convert the dem into an array of value 1
> dem = gdal.Open(dem)
> band = dem.GetRasterBand(1)
> array = band.ReadAsArray()
> array[:,:] = 1
> x_pixels = array.shape[1]
> y_pixels = array.shape[0]
> driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTIFF")
> dataset = driver.Create(extent, x_pixels, y_pixels, 1)
> dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)
>
> # georeferencing using the spatial reference of the input DEM
> world_file = dem.GetGeoTransform()
> proj = dem.GetProjection()
> dataset.SetGeoTransform(world_file)
> dataset.SetProjection(proj)
> dataset.FlushCache()
> ```

- Secondly, you can convert the resulted raster (extent.tif) into a polygon (.shp):

> ```
> # input (dem extent)
> extent = extent.tif
>
> # output (polygon in .shp)
> shp = polygon.shp
>
> # generating the shapefile
> extent = gdal.Open(extent)
> band = extent.GetRasterBand(1)
> driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
> dataset = driver.CreateDataSource(shp)
>
> # georeferencing and layer generation
> srs = osr.SpatialReference()
> srs.ImportFromWkt(extent.GetProjectionRef())
> layer = dataset.CreateLayer("", srs)
> field = ogr.FieldDefn("ID", ogr.OFTInteger)
> layer.CreateField(field)
> gdal.Polygonize(band, None, layer, 0, (), None)
> dataset.Destroy()
> ```

- Finaly, you can use the previous polygon to clip the DEM:

> ```
> # input 1 (dem)
> dem = dem.tif
>
> # input 2 (polygon in .shp)
> shp = polygon.shp
>
> # output (clipped dem)
> clipped_dem = clipped_dem.tif
>
> # clipping the DEM
> with fiona.open(shp, "r") as shapefile:
>     geometry = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
>
> with rasterio.open(dem) as src:
>     out_image, out_transform = mask(src, geometry, crop=True)
>     out_meta = src.meta.copy()
>     out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
>                      "height": out_image.shape[1],
>                      "width": out_image.shape[2],
>                      "transform": out_transform})
>
> with rasterio.open(clipped_dem, "w", **out_meta) as output:
>     output.write(out_image)
> ```